# How to confirm that a payment was successful when using payments gateways?

Tags: php, payment-gateway

This is how payment gateways works as I understand.

1. We send necessary POST Request to Payment Gateway (2checkouts, Paypal, etc).
2. Payments handle by Payments Getaway.
3. Then Payment Getaway send us POST parameters . Assume that Payment Getaway return parameters to example.com/return.php page.

**I know that they send POST parameter like status or something. We can take it to verify the Payments.**

So what we do is, we write a codes in `example.com/return.php page` to verify the payment.

**But** what happen if any user/hacker send all POST parameters (I mean as Payment Gateway send) to  `example.com/return.php page`.

How should I handle about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to verify that you get your POST parameters from the source you expect it to come from. In the case of Paypal, let's use their [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) (or IPN) as an example.

Looking at their IPN [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#id08CKFJ00JYK), they suggest:

> Check email address to make sure that this is not a spoof

However, more importantly, you should look at:

> verify_sign = AtkOfCXbDm2hu0ZELryHFjY-Vb7PAUvS6nMXgysbElEn9v-1XcmSoGtf
>
> Before you can trust the contents of the message, you must first verify that the message came from PayPal. To verify the message, you must send back the contents in the exact order they were received and precede it with the command _notify-validate, as follows:

This means that, when you receive an IPN to `example.com/return.php page`, which can be at any time and not in the normal flow of a HTTP request / response that your end-user will be triggering, you then send this information back to PayPal and get *them* to verify that what you received was both correct and from them.

> PayPal will then send one single-word message, either VERIFIED, if the message is valid, or INVALID if the messages is not valid.

So in your hypothetical example of someone sending spoofed data to your endpoint, PayPal would verify it as invalid anyway, and then you can go about what you need to do to make sure it doesn't happen again (logging, IPTables etc).

Comment: I have not worked with Paypal. I have work with 2checkouts. So I have some questions... Is `verify_sign` is change each each request. I mean each each request. That means after we getting Payment success message, we again send `verify_sign` to Paypal as URL ( like paypal.com/any-url?order_id=1282828&verify_sign=...........). Then it returns success or fail. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah you got it right. Every time you get a request from their servers that a payment has gone through (or from a spoofer), they will provide you with a *unique token*. This changes on every request to your endpoint, so yes it will be different each time. You send this token back to them to make sure it came from them as they hold the source of truth for the token (and the spoofer can't fake this unless they know how to generate that token, which they don't, only the payment gateway does).

Comment: With 2checkouts, it looks slightly different. https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/notifications/. You can calculate that yourself they have indeed sent the right information, as only you and them know your secret word. And obviously you're using SSL encryption / https so this secret word cannot be intercepted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :-) :-)

Comment: Other Payment Gateways just send a POST request with the transaction ID as a notification that the state has changed. You should then get the new state yourself. Someone could fake the notification, but you would still get the real state from the API.